# What is this "Anti-Debug" symbol in Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat, android-device-monitor

I opened **Android Device Monitor** and found this *(see screenshot)*. In the Devices section, there is an Anti-Debug like icon before package `com.facebook.katana`. I cannot figure out what does this mean?

Can anyone help?

[image]